# Premier Pro CC 2015.3 Fast forward causes slow rendering

Tags: premiere, video-editor

I have to make some fast forwarded videos.

If I fast foward a video track in premier pro (1000%, 10x times faster) it causes VERY slow rendering.

I have an i7-4790k@4.6ghz, 16GB ram and an SSD, and they are mostly unused. CPU usage is around 5-8%, ram 700MB and SSD 1% by premier pro.
Normal speed rendering is fully using the CPU, so thats good.

Example:
1 hour video scaled down to ~6 minutes is more than 30 minutes of rendering.. While the normal speed rendering is almost real-time.

The video should be 1080p 29.97fps, h.264 + aac, maximum render quality is off, use previews is on.

Any solution would be appreciated, I already tried different codecs and nesting sequences, didn't really affect the rendering speed and resource usage.

Comment: Is frame blending on? in the render settings at the bottom is a `Time Interpolation` drop down. Frame sampling is the fastest, frame blending is better quality but slower and optical flow even more so.